# Mongo DB Limit with aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have one document show below data have status with Item name

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4aaf6f9588116a6b36e9d4"),
    "item" : "Item_1",
    "status" : 1
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4aaf6f9588116a6b36e9d5"),
    "item" : "Item_2",
    "status" : 1
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4aaf6f9588116a6b36e9d6"),
    "item" : "Item_3",
    "status" : 1
}


.....

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4aaf6f9588116a6b36e9de"),
    "item" : "Item_11",
    "status" : 3
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4aaf6f9588116a6b36e9df"),
    "item" : "Item_12",
    "status" : 3
}
```

I need to select all data with below condition.
 1. Display all unique status.
 2. every unique Status have data array of their own data with 2 data limit.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4aaf6f9588116a6b36e9d7"),
    "status" : 1,
    "data" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e4aaf6f9588116a6b36e9d4"),
            "item" : "Item_1",
            "status" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e4aaf6f9588116a6b36e9d5"),
            "item" : "Item_2",
            "status" : 1
        }
    ]
},
........
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4aaf6f9588116a6b36e9dd"),
    "status" : 3,
    "data" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e4aaf6f9588116a6b36e9dd"),
            "item" : "Item_10",
            "status" : 3
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e4aaf6f9588116a6b36e9de"),
            "item" : "Item_11",
            "status" : 3
        }
    ]
}
```

Please help me. I'm new in mongoDB.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: "$status",
      status: { "$first": "$status" },
      data: { $push: "$$ROOT" } }
  },
  { "$addFields": { data: { $slice: [ "$data", 2 ] } } }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/js4t7e6Fsy0)

Comment: I need 2 data in every group.